# Git - synchronize a branch *exactly* to the files of a new master?

Tags: git

I have a git branch that originally branched from master1, but now needs to be rebased (if that is even the right term?) to master2 instead.

So in other words, I would now like to put "branch" into a status that is identical to "master2" - i.e. has exactly all the same files as (and no more than) master2.

- I've tried merging master2 into branch, which worked. But then, branch still contains old files from master1, which master2 doesn't - and when creating a PR from branch to master2, it tries adding these now obsolete files.
- I've tried git checkout branch, then git reset --hard master2. But now when committing, it fails, saying the tip of my current branch is behind its remote counterpart
- I thought maybe git push --force would help to circumvent that last error, but I can't use that either since it's disabled on the server

Is there any way for me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a simplified tree of the repo history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally, it's right to run `git checkout foo && git reset master2 --hard`. However, as you can't perform a force push, the `foo` in the remote repository can't get updated. We can use another way to make `foo` have the same directories/files with `master2`, without rewriting the history.

```
git checkout foo
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "blah blah" master2^{tree})
```

`git commit-tree` creates a commit object, whose parent is the current head of `foo` and whose tree is the same with the tree of `master2`'s head. When 2 commits have the same tree, they have the same directories and files with the same contents. `git commit-tree` also returns the hash of the commit object. This way, `foo` gets updated to the new commit by a fast-forward merge. Update the local `master2` first if necessary.

Comment: I have to look more closely at `commit-tree`. Nice trick, love it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep history of your branch, just force it on the ref you choose :

```
git branch -f your-branch master2
```

---

However, to keep history of the branch for any reason (here specifically, because server rules forbid a force push), you can merge with the `ours` strategy :

```
# create a copy of master2 and merge your-branch in it, BUT taking nothing from it
git checkout -b master2-copy master2
git merge -s ours your-branch

# at this point we have to reflect the operation on your-branch
# (the second merge is just a fast-forward)
git checkout your-branch
git merge master2-copy

# delete the temp branch
git branch -d master2-copy
```

Then `your-branch` will be the exact same as `master2` but you'll be able to push `your-branch` to remote without force.